# Visual studio build fails while copying files to the bin directory due to file locks by vmwp.exe

Tags: docker, windows-10, locking, hyper-v

I'm running my development environment in Docker containers. Since I have done some updates I'm now experiencing some difficulties when trying to rebuild my project that's running in my Docker container.

My project is running in a Windows Server Core Docker container running IIS, and I'm running the project from a shared volume on my host. I'm able to build the project before starting the docker container, but after the docker container is started the build fails with the following error:

```
Could not copy "C:\path\to\dll\name.dll" to "bin\name.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "vmwp.exe (22604), vmmem (10488)"
```

It seems that the Hyper-V process is locking the DLL files. This clearly wasn't the case before and this seems to be related to some Docker or Windows updates I have done. How can I solve this issue? Do I need to change the process of building the application and running it in my Docker containers?

I have been searching for a while now, and I can't find much about this specific issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Sadly not, for now I'm just doing docker compose down and up for rebuilding the project. I have seen some solutions that used the 'App_Offline' file in the pre build step, but I couldn't get that to work either. While inspecting the docker container I found out that it was IIS inside the container locking the files, but I couldn't find the correct solution for it.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the feedback. With my situation it seems to be a combination of building locally and building within the container (not at the same time :-) that causes it. I'd like to retain the flexibility to do both, as the container is a little slower.

Comment: Hi guys, what SDK and Windows server core versions are you using? I'm currently experiencing this and cant find anything online about the issue...

Comment: +1 I also have this issue. Adding msbuild steps to kill the locking container before build and then start it again after build completes does work - but it's a pain and very slow because you have to wait for the container to die each time you build and then spin up again afterwards.

Comment: I've tried killing app pool, killing iis, killing all sorts of things inside the container, but I think the lock on the files is held by the actual hyper-v process on the host machine and it will only relinquish it if the container is stopped.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue while using `dotnet watch` in a container. Anyone have a solution yet?

Comment: Repo which reproduces the issue with `dotnet watch` -- https://github.com/nickwesselman/dotnet-docker-lock-issue

Comment: Logged this with docker/for-win... +1's there would be helpful.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12028

Comment: Docker redirected me to moby project to log the issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42803

Comment: Do you have active that container in time you are trying to rewrite that file? Its look like this. Do you have a chance to stop container before copying these files? Can you provide some docker image or docker compose file if you have, please?

Comment: @VitezslavSimon see comment above with GitHub repo and Dockerfile that reproduces

Comment: I think your only chance is to define pre build command which forces Docker to stop container you have opened with your files and stop your local HyperV service too. I guess it will stops another services you are hosting on your environment. I know it is not much good advice :(

Comment: I am also getting this issue. The only way I can get it to release the dlls is to take down the container. Anyone make any progress on finding a solution? It definitely seems like it comes from Hyper-V, but I haven't found anything I can tweak that makes me able to build without taking the whole container down.

Answer (score 3):

I've run in the similar problem. Solved by stopping/removing the running application container from docker-for-windows interface. `docker rm -f` will also do.

Comment: If Docker desktop is running you can select the container and click "Stop" under the Actions heading.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution:

1. If you use Docker Windows Containers make sure you have at least Windows 10.0.1809 on both environment(your physical machine and on docker) -run CMDs and you will see on top of it.
2. Use isolation flag with process when you run docker: --isolation process.

On physical machine two vmxxx(lower and higher PID)(don't remember the name exactly) processes was keeping *.dll file(the build was going on docker side where build tools 2019 was used).

Short description:

1. First MSbuild  Error occurred because msbuild tries to delete file - access denied - probably this one vm process handle the file.
2. Second Msbuild Error occurred(the first vmxxx one caused that) showing that copy the same dll file from one direction to another it's not possible due to System lock (4).

Both two vmxxx processes kept one dll file during build on docker. It was visible in tool "Process Explorer"(use full version from Sysinternals)
One vmxxx had lower number of PID which lock the dll file and do not release it before second process with higher number of PID tries do something with it.
And it's one random dll file(s) that is kept by two different process.

Also, using and defining only one CPU without parallel on msbuild did not solved the issue before. Same on docker where you are able to manage the cpu and memory. In the end isolation on docker solved the case.

Isolation should take care of processes when you build project from docker container.